# Add entire model in admin inline

Tags: python, django, django-admin, foreign-keys, inline-formset

These are my models:

## models.py

```
class Company(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(
                        max_length=100,
                        verbose_name = _(u'Nome'),
                        )

    contacts = models.ManyToManyField('Person', through='CompanyContact', verbose_name = _(u'Contatos'))

class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(
                        max_length=200,
                        verbose_name = _(u'Nome'),
                        )

    position = models.CharField(
                            max_length=100,
                            verbose_name = _(u'Cargo'),
                            )

    email = models.EmailField(
                            max_length=100,
                            verbose_name = _(u'Email'),
                            unique=True,
                            )

    employer = models.ForeignKey('Company', verbose_name=_(u'Empresa'))

    addresses = models.ManyToManyField('Address', verbose_name = _(u'Endereços'))
    phones = models.ManyToManyField('Phone', verbose_name = _(u'Telefones'))
```

In company admin:

## admin.py

```
class CompanyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ....

    inlines = (ContactInline,)

    ...
```

## inline

```
class ContactInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = CompanyContact
    extra = 0
    verbose_name = u'Representante'
    verbose_name_plural = u'Representantes'
```

All this configuration generates it in company admin:

[image: Company Admin]

It's ok, but how could I add entire contact admin in admin inline, not just the name property (it's the name because I defined it in person model)? What I want to do is keep contact selection by name in admin inline, but show another properties side by side. For example:

In admin inline:

- Contact: Foo
- Employer: Bar (Employer is a foreign key in person (contact) model).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It might be helpful if you showed how you want to use the result in python.

Comment: I didn't show it because I don't know how to do it. I only need show the entire model field in admin, not just the name field (provided by unicode method).